# Preserve new lines after retrieving data from MySql?

Tags: php

This is my data in my SQL database :

[image]

But this is what I see in php :

[image]

How to preserve new lines ? , Im getting data this way :

```
  $q= "select * from commands where whether_executed=1 and whether_displayed=0 and from_who='".$user_id."' LIMIT 1" ;

//mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$ros=mysql_query($q,$link);
if (mysql_num_rows($ros) > 0 ) {

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros))
{
    // update command set displayed to 1 so it doesnt appear each time
    $cmdId = $row['id'];
    $q2 = "update commands set whether_displayed=1 where from_who='".$user_id."' and id='".$cmdId."' LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($q2);

    $response = $row['answer_type'].'!^#^^#^!'.$row['answer'];

    echo json_encode($response);

}
} else {
echo "NULL";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're sending the response to a browser which doesn't respect the new line character (in terms of display) when the content type is html.

Set your response **content type** to **"text/plain"** and the new lines will be shown in the browser.

Or should you want the page to display as html for any reason you can replace any occurrences of `\n` with `<br/>` before outputting.

Answer (score 0):

This line changes newline characters to "\n":

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Use echo $response instead of json_encode. Or if you have to use json encoding, then accept that newlines are replaced with \n, as newlines are not valid in JSON strings (although \n will be decoded as a newline by JSON parsers).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you need a newline after `.jpg`, so this method is likely to work.

```
str_replace ('.jpg' , '.jpg\n' , $ros);
```

Replace all the `.jpg` with a newline after them.